# Model design: Task Management with Times for web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, database-design, model

I have been asked for building a web application for managing tasks and employees working time.
The idea is that employees click a button when they start working, and click another button when they are finished, so we can measure task's times and employees working times (something like Upwork or any freelancer app).

The question I have is **how can I model the tasks, clock-in, clock-out working times so we don't have performance issues**. (*NOTE: a task can be done by multiple users*)

The first (and simplified) idea that came to my mind was something like:

- **user**

  - id
  - name
- **task**

  - id
  - title
  - description
- **work_time**

  - id
  - *task_id*
  - *user_id*
  - time
  - type ("IN" or "OUT")

So, each time a user clicks "Start Working" button, it creates a work_time record (with type = "IN") and when he finishes and clicks "Finish Working" it creates a work_time record with type = "OUT".

The question that comes to my mind is how is it possible in long-term and with more and more users to not having long-running queries. For example, if I want to know how many hours a task has, I would have to calculate the difference between the IN and OUT times for all the users that worked on that task.

What do you think? Is it a bad approach? Do you know a better way to model that?

Answer (score 1):

I would improve the `work_time` model so that it records "IN" and "OUT" to the same record instead of creating another record to save the OUT time:

- **work_time**

  - id
  - task_id
  - user_id
  - in_time
  - out_time
  - duration(in hours?)

So there's no need to create a query to count the duration between the "IN" time and the "OUT" time.